# UTF8 Encoding with Smartsheet Curl Command

Tags: curl, smartsheet-api

I am using CURL to add a row to a smartsheet but having problems with accented characters.  I have looked but cannot find any information as to how to encode them from a curl command.

Speficially, this command fails:

```
curl -k https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/412336625340000/rows -H "Authorization: Bearer xx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST
-d "[{\"toBottom\":true},{\"toBottom\":true,\"cells\": [{\"columnId\": 2259324614535044, \"value\": \"203965\", \"format\": \",,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,\"},{\"columnId\": 6762924241900000, \"value\": \"Augmentation des trous de centrage des deux radiateurs (passage de 2mm à 2.5mm)\nAjout d¿un fournisseur sur la barrette 5pts ( J4/J10 )\", \"format\": \",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1\"}]}]" -s -S
```

with this error message:

```
{
  "errorCode" : 1008,
  "message" : "Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Field \"value\" was not parsable. Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x20\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@38dbf5a7; line: , column: 241].",
  "refId" : "13n01oko08lux"
}
```

How do I encode characters in a curl command?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Michael

Answer (score 1):

This is a curl question.

Copying and pasting the characters from your post work for me on a Mac with no additional changes.

I observe the same error using curl on Windows.

Here's the best workaround I can find:

- Use notepad++ to save the json payload as UTF-8 *without BOM*
- Tell curl to load the payload from a file

Here is Payload.json - converted to UTF-8 (no BOM)

`[ {"toTop": true,"cells":[{"columnId":5759377954105220,"value": "API Test: à¿à"}]} ]`

Here is my curl command:

`curl -X POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/5670346721388420/rows -H "authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxx" -H "content-type: application/json"  -d @payload.json`